# Find all the cosets of Dihderal group 6 with subgroup H

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let H={$\rho_{0}, \rho_{2}, \rho_{4}$}, a subgroup of D6, the group of symmetries.  Where $\rho_{0}$=identity permutation, $\rho_{2}$=(1,3,5)(2,4,6) and $\rho_{4}$=(1,5,3)(2,6,4).

How would you find all the left and right cosets of H and determine whether this is a normal subgroup or D6?  I notice already that H is generated by $\rho_{2}$ but I'm not getting any further than that.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

do you notice that $H$ is a Sylow 3-subgroup? if there were $4$ Sylow 3-subgroups then that would require $8$ elements of order $3$ which obviously cannot be the case. so $H$ is normal.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?  H is an S3 subgroup because $\rho_2$ Generates H right?  What do you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: He's using Sylow Theorems, which tells you that since the order of the group is 12=3*4. You will have either 1 or 4 subgroups of order 3. If you have only one subgroup of order 3 then it is normal. He gave the reason why there can't be 4.

Answer (score 0):

The left and right cosets of $H$ are defined as follows:

$aH  = \{ah \,|\,h \in H\}$ and $Ha = \{ha \, | \, h \in H\}$, where $a$ is an element of the ambient group $G$ (in this case $D_6$). Building on this definition, a subgroup is normal iff the following is true:

$aH = Ha$ for every $a \in D_6$. An equivalent condition is $a^{-1}Ha = H$ for every $a \in D_6$.